# posting JSON to Spring rest controller

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, post

I got stuck on sending POST to my rest controller. When I try to update my entry, I get 415 status. I have this error in my web application, written in angular JS and chrome tool for rest API.

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateEntry(@RequestBody Entry entry) {
    System.out.println("editing: " + entry.toString());
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm trying to send something like this:

```
{"id":"5471db49b0ca59357d6beded","name":"EADS 3 Sigma Nearchos"}
```

My entry contains only two fields: String id, String name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Framework raised library requirements, including Jackson. You should update to Jackson 2.1+ when using Spring 4.1.x.

Check out the [migration page on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries) for more details.